# Why use Core data for storage?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

*What is the meaning of it?*

*What is Core Data?*

*What is so special about it?*

---

When I went to create a navigation based application it has a check box for Core Data.

If I use this option then what will it work well for my project?

Also, when i choose View Controller Based Application while creating a new project the Core Data check box is not available. Why is this?

Comment: please read the documentation before asking such questions, CoreData is a database system for storing data. If you don't know what it is then you will probably don't need it so leave it unchecked

Comment: not like that friend i try to find out what is going on with that checkmark.ok it is for database as u said .then what is sqlLite?

Comment: what the checkmark does is to set up a .sqlite file and sample code for accessing it (including 'saveChanges:' and so on)

Comment: vote down- These questions could have been answered with a general search on the web or looking at the Documentation.

Comment: @iPortable: Core Data is **not** a database system. It's an **interface** (an API) to one.

Comment: @BoltClock yes you're absolutely right. I should have slow down next time and think whats exactly behind the name, what it represents

Comment: Actually, Core data is not even an interface to a database. Core Data is actually an object graph management system that has the option of persisting the graph. SQLite is just one of the persistence options. The true function of Core Data is to serve as the model layer of a Model-View-Controller design app. Confusing it with a database causes a lot of grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, sqlite is a lib for db too, and core data is an object-c lib for database... both are a good way to manage db, you have just to choose your favorite one...

and this may help you:

http://tapity.com/iphone-app-development/readwrite-data-on-the-iphone-property-lists-sqlite-or-core-data/

Comment: Actually, Core Data isn't an "object-c lib for database". See my comment on the parent. The database functionality is really a minor part of its function.

Comment: @TechZen: yes, ok, you're right... but reading the comments i just figured out that the focus of the question was "why should i use 'core data' when i could use 'sqlite'..."

Answer (score 1):

Those are broad questions better answered by Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is a persistant store of your object graph, It can be backed by sqllite, but doesn't have to be.

if you are unsure how you want to store data, CD is a good choice, it is very well optimised. as a rule you only want to use something other than core data if you have a very good reason.

read the apple docs for a better overview, and there is a fantastic book by Marcus Zarra. If you are going to be developing for iOS it is well worth learning about, even if you choose not to use it.

with regards to why it isn't available in the VC based application, there is no reason not to use it with a View controller based app, but you would have to type the code to implement it, there isn't a default design pattern from apple for it in the templates, so you would have to decide how to impliment it best for your use case.